# in Kafka, how to make consumers consume from local partition?

Tags: parallel-processing, apache-kafka, local, distributed-system

Just to make the scenario simple.

number of consumers == number of partitions == Kafka broker numbers

If deploy the consumers on the same machines where the brokers are, how to make each consumer only consume the messages locally? The purpose is to cut all the network overhead.

I think we can make it if each consumer can know the partition_id on their machines, but I don't know how? or is there other directions to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper [zk address] --describe --topic [topic_name]` tells you which broker hosts the leader for each partition. Then you can use manual partition assignment for each consumer to make sure it consumes from a local partition.

Comment: Is it possible to get the local partition id in runtime? it would be better not to hard code it.

Comment: Yes. Take a look at Kafka's Metadata API: https://kafka.apache.org/protocol#The_Messages_Metadata

Answer (score 1):

Probably not worth the effort because partition leadership can change and then you would have to rebalance all your consumers to be local again. You can save the same amount of network bandwidth with less effort by just reducing the replication factor from 3 to 2.

Comment: thanks for the reminding but why replication factor could affect network bandwidth on consumer side?

Comment: @HongjiChen it's doesn't effect consumer side but it's the same shared network for producer and consumer and you cannot consume what has not been produced.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use the Admin Client API.
First you can use the describeTopics() methods for getting information about topics in the cluster. From the DescribeTopicResult you can access to TopicPartitionInfo with information about partitions for each topic. From there you can access to the Node through the leader(). Node contains the host() and you can check if it's the same as the host your consumer is running or id() and the consumer should have the information about the broker-id running on the same machine (in general it's an information you can define upfront). More infor on Admin Client API at the following JavaDoc :

https://kafka.apache.org/0110/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/AdminClient.html